# LINQ, Generics y declaraciones

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Estoy estudiando un curso sobre LINQ en el que se explica el uso de Generics, extensión de métodos y Fluent API sobre esta tecnología.

Me he encontrado con las siguientes expresiones:

```
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg);

public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector);
```

No me quedan clara dos cosas:

1. ¿Por qué se utilizan los modificadores `in` y `out` en la primera y no en la segunda expresión?
2. ¿Por qué se define solo `TResult` como tipo utilizando en el método `Select`?

Gracias.

Comment: en que contexto estas obteniendo esas lineas de codigo ? la segunda parece ser una extension, pero no se a que llamas "define solo como tipo", alli no define ningun tipo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si analizamos la documentacion

[Func< T,TResult> Delegate](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=netframework-4.5)

observaras que el `out` es solo para que te quede claro que ese parametro que define el `delegate` es de salida, pero no tienes que indicarlo cuando lo declaras.

Esa primer linea de codigo no se utiza en tu desarrollo, es solo a nivel de documentacion.